# Cross-referencing location to AdWords on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm fairly new to Google Analytics and one of my clients is concerned that he's paying for AdWords domestically but paying out to international customers, which he can't service.

This raised the question for me: Is there a way to correlate Paid Search results to a session location?

Answer (score 1):

You can view geographic data for your adwords traffic by navigating or filtering to google / cpc (source / medium) and adding a secondary dimension for country, continent etc.

Hope this helps.

Tom